# Is it possible to change the size of a "configurable form"?

Tags: install4j

I'm using a **"Configurable Form"** component (install4j v5.1.5) and it's a bit too small to hold all the informations I want to put on it. It's scrollable, but I'd like to make it a bit higher so user won't have to scroll. I tried to uncheck "Scrollable" in the form properties, but it just removes the scroll bar and doesn't **change the size**. Is it possible ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the window size of the installer application. Select the "Installer" node and increase the value of the "Window height" property.

Comment: Perfect. Didn't know it changes the size of all windows of the installer but that's no problem at all. Thanks a lot for you quick and exact reply.